# Hitting API request in ViewPager Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager and used fragmentpageradapter, now I have 3 fragments and in every fragment I need to make a http request (i.e, hit a api),
I don't want to hit all the api for 3 fragments at a time instead I require to hit the api only when the respective page is the current item visible.

I have already tried setting offscreenlimit, but it did not help. What else can I try?

```
viewPager.setOffscreenLimit(0);
```

Comment: did you get the solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done by using [OnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) provided by ViewPager class

```
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // communicate with Fragment here
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

First remove the API calls from *onCreateView* of fragments, then use this event listener to check which page is selected, according to the selected position you can communicate to the fragment to call the required API.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your Fragment

```
private boolean hasBeenVisibleOnce = false;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(true);

    if (this.isVisible()) {
        if (visible && !hasBeenVisibleOnce) {
            new NetCheck().execute();
            hasBeenVisibleOnce= true;
        }
    }
}
```

you can use setUserVisibleHint to check if a fragment is visible to the user. You want to add another boolean (called hasBeenVisibleOnce) to determine if the fragment has been visible at least once. This is to prevent the HTTP Request to be fired multiple times